Writing a Mongoose/MongoDB Lookup Query Without Using $text
(Before I get too deep into a rabbit hole where I beat my head against the wall the whole way down, I figured I'd ask for help.)
To my understanding, the conventional way of doing a lookup is by using the $text query, but after first marking all the searchable fields on each schema. This is sort of a last resort as I have a bunch of schemas (schemata?) now. What I have tried (and failed) to do instead is this:
router.get(
  "/:collection",
  async ({ params: { collection }, query: { query } }, res) => {
    const collections = mongoose.modelNames();
    if (!collections.includes(collection.toLowerCase())) {
      return res.status(400).send(
        `The collection '${collection}' does not exist. Select from one of the following: (${
          collections.length
        })\n${collections
          .sort()
          .map(name => "- " + name)
          .join("\n")}`
      );
    }
    const MODEL = mongoose.model(collection);
    const $regex = new RegExp(query, "i");
    const searchFields =
      "name/title/subtitle/_id/username/about/description".split("/");
    const search = searchFields.map(field => ({
      [field]: { $exists: true, $type: "string", $regex },
    }));

    try {
      const entries = await MODEL.find({ $or: search });
      console.log({ entries });

      return res.status(entries.length ? 200 : 204).json(entries);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err.message);

After retrieving the model, I want to return the documents that match the query regex in any of the name,title,subtitle, (etc) fields. I thought adding $type: "string" and $exists: true to the query would help, but it doesn't seem to.
If the only way to do it is to use a $text search then I will, but if you can tailor your query with $and and $or, it seems like there should be a way to make this work. If there is a way to make it work, but by sacrificing performance, I won't be able to consider it.
Ultimately, what I'm trying to create is a frontend feature (using Next) similar to Facebook's lookup (or any social media platform) where you start typing "@..." and it retrieves a handful of suggestions. This is the backend logic I'm trying to work out (in case that was unclear to anyone).
Thanks!
